# What could be reason it crashes when I use vector::erase?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I am trying to do some operation on vector. And calling erase on vector only at some case.

here is my code

```
while(myQueue.size() != 1)
{
    vector<pair<int,int>>::iterator itr = myQueue.begin();
    while(itr != myQueue.end())
    {
        if(itr->first%2 != 0)
            myQueue.erase(itr);
        else
        {
            itr->second = itr->second/2;
            itr++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting crash in 2nd iteration.And I am getting this crash with message vector iterator incompatible .

What could be the reason of crash?

Comment: The question is hard to understand as is. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: The question was just missing the question mark. Last line.

Comment: And you should assign the return value of `erase` to your iterator, i.e. `itr = myQueue.erase(itr);`. In this scenario, your program will probably crash.

Comment: @Nick no, the last two sentences were not present (they were added in the 5m edit limit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `erase()` is called the iterator is invalidated and that iterator is then accessed on the next iteration of the loop. [`std::vector::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) returns the next iterator after the erased iterator:

```
itr = myQueue.erase(itr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given an iterator range `[b, e)` where `b` is the beginning and `e` one past the end of the range for a vector an erase operation on an iterator `i` somewhere in the range will invalidate all iterators from `i` upto `e`. Which is why you need to be very careful when calling `erase`. The `erase` member does return a new iterator which you can you for subsequent operations and you ought to use it:

```
 itr = myQueue.erase( itr );
```

Another way would be to swap the `i` element and the last element and then erase the last. This is more efficient since less number of moves of elements beyond `i` are necessary.

```
myQueue.swap( i, myQueue.back() );
myQueue.pop_back();
```

Also, from the looks of it, why are you using `vector`? If you need a `queue` you might as well use `std::queue`.

Comment: The swap version changes the order of the elements (don't know whether that matters), and while the name is `myQueue`, the operations used on it are not supported by a real FIFO queue (`std::queue`)

Comment: What operations are you talking about? Also, a `vector` is *not* a sorted container. I don't see the point of your objection. My last paragraph has the same question btw -- why is the OP using a `vector` if (s)he needs a queue.

Comment: The two points are that: a vector has an order, the order of insertion of the elements. If that is part of the required semantics, then the swap will change that order. The second point is that the operation in the question could not be applied to `std::queue`, so your suggestion to use a queue makes no sense.

Comment: There'd probably be no need for an `erase` from somewhere in the middle from a queue data structure. The code would be much simplified and idiomatic. Such a problem as discussed in the question wouldn't happen. Secondly, this is not a plain queue, but one based on a `pair` -- something tells me there's more than insertion order at play here.

Answer (score 2):

That is undefined behavior. In particular, once you erase an iterator, it becomes invalid and you can no longer use it for anything. The idiomatic way of unrolling the loop would be something like:

```
for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ) {
   if ( it->first % 2 != 0 )
      it = v.erase(it);
   else {
      it->second /= 2;
      ++it;
   }
}
```

But then again, it will be more efficient and idiomatic not to roll your own loop and rather use the algorithms:

```
v.erase( std::remove_if( v.begin(),
                         v.end(),
                         []( std::pair<int,int> const & p ) {
                             return p.first % 2 != 0;
                       }),
         v.end() );
std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), 
                []( std::pair<int,int> const & p ) {
                    return std::make_pair(p.first, p.second/2);
                } );
```

The advantage of this approach is that there is a lesser number of copies of the elements while erasing (each valid element left in the range will have been copied no more than once), and it is harder to get it wrong (i.e. misuse an invalidated iterator...) The disadvantage is that there is no `remove_if_and_transform` so this is a two pass algorithm, which might be less efficient if there is a large number of elements.

Comment: I added the one way pass fashion using Boost.Range to my answer. It might be more efficient, but it does not look much better than the OP's original code.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating while modifying a loop is generally tricky.

Therefore, there is a specific C++ idiom usable with non-associative sequences: the erase-remove idiom.

It combines the use of the `remove_if` algorithm with the range overload of the `erase` method:

```
myQueue.erase(
    std::remove_if(myQueue.begin(), myQueue.end(), /* predicate */),
    myQueue.end());
```

where the predicate is expressed either as a typical functor object or using the new C++11 lambda syntax.

```
// Functor
struct OddKey {
    bool operator()(std::pair<int, int> const& p) const {
        return p.first % 2 != 0;
    }
};

/* predicate */ = OddKey()

// Lambda
/* predicate */ = [](std::pair<int, int> const& p) { return p.first % 2 != 0; }
```

The lambda form is more concise but may less self-documenting (no name) and only available in C++11. Depending on your tastes and constraints, pick the one that suits you most.

---

It is possible to elevate your way of writing code: use [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

```
typedef std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > PairVector;

void pass(PairVector& pv) {
    auto const filter = [](std::pair<int, int> const& p) {
        return p.first % 2 != 0;
    };
    auto const transformer = [](std::pair<int, int> const& p) {
        return std::make_pair(p.first, p.second / 2);
    };

    pv.erase(
        boost::transform(pv | boost::adaptors::filtered( filter ),
                         std::back_inserter(pv),
                         transformer),
        pv.end()
    );
}
```

You can find [`transform`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/transform.html) and the [`filtered` adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) in the documentation, along with many others.